# Operators for a Perturbed Hamiltonian: Heisenberg Picture ($\hat{x}$, $\hat{p}$)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

### Problem

I am trying to calculate the Equations of Motion in the Heisenberg picture for $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ in a perturbed Hamiltonian,
$$
    \tag{1}
    \hat{H} = \hat{H}_0 + \hat{H}'
$$

Assume the Heisenberg Equations of Motion are given by,

$$
    \tag{2}
    \frac{\partial \hat{A}(t)}{\partial t} = -i\left[ \hat{A}(t),\hat{H} \right]
$$
with $\hbar=1$ to simplify.

## Issue

Can I use the operators $\hat{x}(t)$, $\hat{p}(t)$ for the unperturbed hamiltonian, $\hat{H}_0$, in Equation $(2)$ to get the perturbed equations of motion?

- Is this the correct approach?
- Do I need a correction in $\hat{x}(t)$, $\hat{p}(t)$ for the perturbation?

### Specifics

In my case, $\hat{H}_0$ is an oscillator such that,

$$
    \hat{H}_0 = \frac{1}{2m}\hat{p}^2 + \frac{k}{2}\hat{x}^2
$$
and the perturbation, $\hat{H}'$, is quartic in $\hat{x}$ like $\lambda\frac{1}{4}\hat{x}^4$ with a coupling constant of $\lambda$

Comment: ...  equations of motion for what, exactly?

Comment: any Heisenberg operator $\hat{A}(t)$ but specifically $\hat{x}(t)$ and $\hat{p}(t)$. I've just added the time dependences of the operators as I just realised it might not have been immediately clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your answer sidestepped the whole question.

When you do the same for $\hat p$ you'll find that its derivative depends on $\hat x$, and on $\lambda$.

But these coupled equations can then be solved as a second order equation for the terms individually, which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: yeah agreed, thanks for your time :). The question was whether I needed special treatment to $\hat{x}$ because of the perturbation. You're right though, the solution is incomplete unless you solve for $\hat{p}$ and relate the two. I've edited the end of my answer slightly as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you do need to treat it as a perturbation and no correction is necessary...

Calculating the commutator,
        \begin{equation}
   \left[\hat{x}, \hat{H}\right]
   =
   \left[
    \hat{x},
    \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} 
    - \frac{k}{2}\hat{x}^2 
    + \frac{\lambda}{4}\hat{x}^4
   \right]
  \end{equation}
        but as $\left[\hat{x},\hat{x}\right]=0$,
        \begin{equation}
   \left[\hat{x}, \hat{H}\right]
   =
   \left[
    \hat{x},
    \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}
   \right]
   = \frac{1}{2m}\left[\hat{x},\hat{p}\hat{p}\right]
   =
   \frac{1}{2m}
   \left[\hat{x},\hat{p}\right]\hat{p}
   +
   \frac{1}{2m}
   \hat{p}\left[\hat{x},\hat{p}\right]
  \end{equation}
        rmembering I'm setting $\hbar=1$ so we get,
        \begin{equation}
   \tag{1}
   \left[\hat{x}, \hat{H}\right]
   =
   \frac{i}{2m}
   \hat{p}
   +
   \frac{i}{2m}
   \hat{p}
   =
   \frac{i}{m}
   \hat{p}
  \end{equation}
        Using Equation $(1)$ with the Heisenberg equations of motion,
        \begin{equation}
   \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \hat{x}
   = 
   -i\left[\hat{x}, \hat{H}\right]
   =
   \frac{\hat{p}}{m}
  \end{equation}

The same can be done for $\hat{p}$. The two can then be related to get two pairs of $1^\text{st}$ and $2^\text{nd}$ order coupled ODEs